# Performance of <= and >= when used on floating point types

Tags: c#, performance, operators

I've heard that when using the `<=` or `>=` operators it is automatically optimized by the compilers as such: `(int)Variable >= 2` becomes `(int)Variable > 1`. Is this true in any way for floating point types? It seems to me like `(float)Variable >= 2` can't be optimized to `(float)Variable > 1.999999999` without heading off to infinity, either causing it to be impossible or to cause a hit to performance. (I am aware the difference in performance may be minuscule, but this is just something I would like to know)

Comment: There are cpu instructions for all this `JNE` Jump if not equal, 
`JE` Jump if equal, 
`JG` Jump if greater, 
`JLE` Jump if less than or equal,
`JL` Jump if less than,
`JGE` Jump if greater or equal. However your biggest performance hit will be if these variable are boxed. Infact if you have a performance issue, why not use a benchmarker and test this stuff for your self?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, if you check the generated IL code. For instance, consider the following class:

```
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
        float a = 4;
        float b = 5;
        bool result = a >= b;
    }
}
```

The generated IL code is the following:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 22 (0x16)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] float32,
            [1] float32,
            [2] bool
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.r4 4
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: ldc.r4 5
        IL_000c: stloc.1
        IL_000d: ldloc.0
        IL_000e: ldloc.1
        IL_000f: clt.un
        IL_0011: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0012: ceq
        IL_0014: stloc.2
        IL_0015: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2072
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

If you read the above generated IL code (use as a reference to the IL commands [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)), you will notice that this is not true.

In a few words, in the above IL code the `float` numbers are loaded into the stack and then `clt.un` operation is used, which:

> Push 1 (of type int32) if value1 < value2, unsigned or unordered, else push 0.

Then the result of this operation is compared for equality with 0, using `ceq`, which:

> Push 1 (of type int32) if value1 equals value2, else push 0.

and the result of the above is assigned to the result `variable`.